# How to reset Production Amplify DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am still currently in development stage of a site and I would like to clean the current live DB completely as well as flush the previous schemas. As I am making so many changes to the schemas that I am not longer able to `amplify push`

Is this possible with AWS amplify?

```
Attempting to edit the global secondary index byDivision on the DivisionTable table in the Division stack. 
An error occurred during the push operation: Attempting to edit the global secondary index
```

byDivision on the DivisionTable table in the Division stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run:

```
amplify api remove
amplify api push
```

so it will remove the API (including DDB). Make sure you firstly check out on the correct environment.

After that you need to add API once again using:

```
amplify api add
```

However if you want to do create a clean environment from scratch, then simply:

```
amplify env remove <env_name>
amplify init
```

It will firstly remove the environment and then recreate it. It takes a while but works fine!

Comment: `amplify api remove` would remove the local version I thought?

Comment: Yes, but if you push the changes (`amplify api push`), then it will update the backed in AWS.

Comment: Sure, no problem :) The Amplify CLI is a little bit strange at the beginning, but you will get used to it